# How to make threading timer work when android device is unplugged?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to change the phone ringer state after a certain amount of time using Threading timer. I'm debugging on an Oppo android device.
So on button click I change the ringer state to vibrate and I want it to get back to normal after a certain amount of time inputted using a time picker.
It works fine when I deploy the app to the device while its plugged but then, if I unplug the device and run the app, it changes the ringer state to vibrate on button click but then the timer doesn't work and it doesn't return to normal state!

Here is the very simple xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="RingDemo.TimerPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <TimePicker Time="00:00" x:Name="time" />
        <Button Text="Select time" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

and this is the code behind:

```
public partial class TimerPage : ContentPage
    {
        TimeSpan triggerTime;
        TimeSpan startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
        TimeSpan periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        private bool timerConsumed = false;

        System.Threading.Timer timer;

        public TimerPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void checkCurrentTime()
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Hour == triggerTime.Hours && DateTime.Now.Minute == triggerTime.Minutes)
            {
                DependencyService.Get<IChangeRingModeService>().changeRingModeToNormal();
                timerConsumed = true;
            }

            else
                return;

            // check if timer work is done and kill the timer if true
            if (timerConsumed == true)
            {
                timer.Dispose();
                timerConsumed = false;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // set trigger time equals to time picker time
            triggerTime = time.Time;

            // change phone ring state to vibration
            DependencyService.Get<IChangeRingModeService>().changeRingModeToVibrate();

            // run a function that checks for time and compares it with trigger time
            timer = new System.Threading.Timer((entry) =>
            {
                checkCurrentTime();
            }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
        }
    }
```

I'm still new to this so I expect it to work when the device is unplugged since the app is already deployed to it but i guess i'm wrong?

Comment: Unless you are using an OS-based service or scheduler, your code will not continue to run indefinitely (otherwise your device would grind to a stop as every developer/app would be doing it) You should review how JobScheduler (and|or Foregrounded services) work in the Android OS : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/replacing-services-jobs-android-oreo-8-0/